# HP G8 1040 with Ubuntu 21.10, power/freezing problem

Tags: power-management, hp, freeze, 21.10

I have new **HP elitebook G8 1040** and I want to use **Ubuntu 21.10** (because of some newer package versions). However, Ubuntu becomes unresponsive quite frequently (Gnome freezes and even ctrl+alt+fn is not working). Is there any chance to debug such issue or I just have to wait for a new LTS release? Some details:

```
Bios version: T93 Ver. 01.07.03
Kernel: 5.13.0-27-generic
```

System may freeze right after boot and log-in. But more frequently after waking-up from sleep (opening notebook lid) and logging in. Screen shows opened windows and programs and then after few seconds hangs.

Thank you!

Comment: How long has it been since the system was installed? Did these problems start right away or sometime after? Why do you think waiting for the next LTS will be helpful? Have you tried 18.04 or 20.04 and everything works in that release? When you keep open a resource monitor, when your system hangs, do you notice anything that seems out of the ordinary? Is your system fully up-to-date?

Comment: It is fresh install. I tried also Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and it was not freezing. When system hangs it is not possible to open anything, so I did not tried to check resource monitor (but I will try keep it opened). And system is up-to-date.

Comment: I encounter freezing just few seconds after boot and log-in even more often (two times in this week...). I do not catch to open resource monitor in such situations. And also after lid open, when computer was few minutes in sleep mode (I noticed, that keyboard backlight is responding to my typing, lights up/down as I write or not, fan is working, so cpu is doing something, but screen is black).